# Resolving DTD paths using lxml

Tags: python, lxml, dtd, resolver

I have a set of DTD's which internally call other DTD's. All of these files are currently being stored in the main directory of my project. My project is starting to look really clogged, so I was hoping to move the DTD's to a new folder. I found a way to resolve the DTD path for the main file using a resolver like the one on [this page](http://lxml.de/resolvers.html#uri-resolvers). The problem is that though it correctly resolves the path to the main DTD, it appears to resolve the path to the internally called files twice. Because this path doesn't exist, the code errors out.

My Resolver:

```
class DTDResolver(etree.Resolver):
    def resolve(self, system_url, public_id, context):
        print system_url
        newPath = "DTDs/" + system_url
        return self.resolve_filename(newPath, context)
```

It's Results:

```
us-patent-grant-v40-2004-12-02.dtd
DTDs/wipo.ent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3032, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:68121)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1786, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102470)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1674, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101299)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1074, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96481)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91290)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92476)
  File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91772)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: failed to load external entity "DTDs/DTDs/wipo.ent", line 237, column 7
```

I was able to create a work around, but it seems incredibly hacky so I'm wondering if there is a better way to fix the issue

```
class DTDResolver(etree.Resolver):
    def resolve(self, system_url, public_id, context):
        print system_url
        if system_url.startswith("DTDs/"):
            return self.resolve_filename(system_url, context)
        else:
            newPath = "DTDs/" + system_url
            return self.resolve_filename(newPath, context)
```

Comment: Have you considered correcting the system identifiers in the DTDs so that the relative references are still correct?  Or is that not feasible?

Comment: I have considered it, and it would be feasible for right now, but I'm not sure how it would work in the future. It seems to me right now that resolving would be more practical in that every time location changed or I got a new DTD I wouldn't have to manually fix the individual files